# How long can I use prior versions of Azure SDK once a new version ships?

Tags: windows, deployment, sdk, azure, upgrade

Currently the newest version of Azure SDK is 1.5, but I'm using 1.4 and don't want to waste time upgrading right now.

Will I face any problems deploying a package built against version 1.4 onto live cloud? How long (approximately) can I continue building against version 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the pre-PDC CTP SDK, all RTM versions of the SDK are supported and continue to be supported.  Before I left MSFT, there were customers still on v1.0 and it had literally been > year.  I can't find any official documentation on SDK support windows, but we used to say the support window was very long and that you would be given a lot of warning if things were going to be deprecated (like CTP SDK versions).

Comment: It would be good to have an official confirmation (from someone like @smarx) of the official policy for this. I'm in the situation where I may build applications for customers that rely on the current 1.5 SDK -- I'll need to know in good time how long this will be supported.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an official answer.  I would not be surprised however to hear that SDK support is tied to OS support lifecycle.

Comment: Ah, now that would make sense. So, in other words, the SDK 1.x series will work as long as Windows 2008 R2 is available on Azure.